# Condition with square roots for positivity of polynomial on interval

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

I recently encountered the following curious property :

Let $f$ be a quadratic real polynomial, with $f(0),f(\frac{1}{2}),f(1)$ positive.

Then $f$ is nonnegative on $[0,1]$ if and only if

$$
\Bigg|\sqrt{f(1)}-\sqrt{f(0)}\ \Bigg| \leq 2\sqrt{f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}
$$

I found a straightforward but somewhat painstaking, computational proof of this (I will eventually post that proof if no feedback arrives). I am hoping for better proofs, which is why I'm posting it here.

Comment: what was that  straightforward but somewhat painstaking, computational proof? (at least some steps...). I am saying this because someone just post same thing as you did will not be helpful to you...

Comment: i would try $$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an improved version of my original proof :
Let $\delta=f(\frac{1}{2})-\left(\frac{\sqrt{f(1)}-\sqrt{f(0)}}{2}\right)^2$
and $a=\sqrt{f(0)}, b=\sqrt{f(1)}$. Using Lagrange interpolation, we have

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
f(t) &=& f(0) (1-t)(1-2t) + f(\frac{1}{2})4t(1-t)+f(1)t(2t-1) \\
     &=& a^2 (1-t)(1-2t) + ((a-b)^2+4\delta) t(1-t)+ b^2 t(2t-1) \\
     &=& (bt-a(1-t))^2+4\delta t(1-t) \tag{1}
\end{array}
$$

If $\delta \geq 0$, then $f$ is nonnegative on $[0,1]$ by (1).
Conversely, suppose $\delta <0$. There is a $t_0\in (0,1)$ such that $bt_0=a(1-t_0)$ (namely, $t_0=\frac{a}{a+b}$), and from (1) we deduce $f(t_0)=4\delta t_0(1-t_0)<0$, so
$f$ is not nonnegative on $[0,1]$.